# Getting list out of python list of list

Tags: python

I am using a list of list as follows:

```
L = [['a', 4], ['b', 2], ['c', 13]]
```

I want to generate a new list for all the numbers which are in the second position in each set of the list:

```
L =  [4, 2, 13]
```

Is there any shortcut in python to get the above list?

Comment: yeah, two possible ways to do the same thing, i was unaware of zip, so couldn't find it earlier

Comment: @pradeep [Here's a link to the documentation on `zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
>>> L = [['a', 4], ['b', 2], ['c', 13]]
>>> print [i[1] for i in L]
[4, 2, 13]
```

This accesses the second item in each list (remember that indexing starts at zero, so `1` gets the second index)

Comment: Can I assign it to new List ?

Comment: @pradeep Yes! Just do `new_list = [i[1] for i in L]` or something like that